# Best practice with multi country set up - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, multicurrency

I'm opening my store using Magento 2 and looking for some advice as I don't really understand the differences between websites, stores and store views.

It's a single business running on different countries.

URL structure will be:
www.mystore.com/en-us/ - US store
www.mystore.com/en-uk/ - UK store
www.mystore.com/en-au/ - AU store
www.mystore.com/it-it/ - IT store
www.mystore.com - International store (everything but US, UK, AU and IT)

- Inventory is shared across all stores
- Product attributes are different in each country (description, images, price and currency - beware I need to set each price manually, not auto convert through currency converters)
- Tax are different for each country
- Shipping options are the same (we only use one warehouse), but shipping costs and timings are different
- Static page content (images, text) is different
- I don't mind if customer database is global or splitted, but I want to prevent any user to register an account in multiple countries.

If anyone would have any advices on how to configure Magento would be awesome.

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Comment: @MagenX "I don't really understand the differences between websites, stores and store views." - I think the question is clear: should UK/AU/IT be different websites or just different stores and why?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html

Comment: i think the easiest way to understand it -- is to read some docs and create two demo stores, then websites, etc.  this is your business so you must test it anyway before start.

Answer (score 2):

> "Product attributes are different in each country (description, images, price and currency - beware I need to set each price manually, not auto convert"

Based on this sole requirement you are looking at individual websites per "site".